# HAproxy clustering (active/active or active/passive) for openstack

Tags: cluster-computing, openstack, haproxy

what type of active/active or active/passive cluster is better for Ha-proxy clustering ?

with pros and cons (in hardware or software)?
(I want to run HA-proxy in front of my **Openstack**)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, read the [ask] page and update your question.